# Joining nested individual properties by comma

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am trying to join the array of objects internal properties with the comma `,` like as below

```
const multiSpaceIdentityInformation = spaces?.reduce(
    (acc, space) => {
      acc.roomName = `${acc.roomName},${space.spaceIdentity.roomName}`;
      acc.roomNumber = `${acc.roomNumber},${space.spaceIdentity.roomNumber}`;
      acc.storyName = `${acc.storyName},${space.buildingStory?.name}`;
      acc.spaceNumber = `${acc.spaceNumber},${space.spaceIdentity.number}`;
      acc.spaceName = `${acc.spaceName},${space.spaceIdentity.name}`;
      return acc;
    },
    {
      roomName: 'N/A',
      roomNumber: 'N/A',
      storyName: 'N/A',
      spaceNumber:'N/A',
      spaceName: 'N/A'
    }
  );
```

But somehow, I cannot display the information even I have spaces holding the array of objects.
What I am trying to display is if there is no information, I would like to say 'N/A' as the default option.

I am accessing the above information here

```
 const identityData = [
    { label: 'Room Number', value: multiSpaceIdentityInformation.roomNumber },
    { label: 'Room Name', value: multiSpaceIdentityInformation.roomName },
    { label: 'Level', value: multiSpaceIdentityInformation.storyName },
    { label: 'Space Number', value: multiSpaceIdentityInformation.spaceNumber },
    { label: 'Space Name', value: multiSpaceIdentityInformation.spaceName }
  ];
```

Could anyone please let me know where it goes wrong with the above code?
Many thanks in advance!

Sample input

```
{
  "Spaces": [
    {
      "spaceGeometry":{
        "roomName": ""
        "roomNumber": "",
        "number": "number1"
        "name": "space1"
      },
       "buildingStory":{
        "name": "story1"
      }
    },
    {
      "spaceGeometry":{
        "roomName": ""
        "roomNumber": "",
        "number": "number2"
        "name": "space2"
      },
       "buildingStory":{    
        "name": "story2"
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

and desired output be like

```
multiSpaceIdentityInformation.roomName = "N/A"
multiSpaceIdentityInformation.roomNumber = "N/A"
multiSpaceIdentityInformation.storyName = "story1, story2"
multiSpaceIdentityInformation.spaceNumber = "number1, number2"
multiSpaceIdentityInformation.spaceName = "space1, space2"
```

Comment: Please add `spaces` array and expected output.

Comment: @HassanImam, I have updated the desired output

Comment: You're reducing an array to get a single object whose keys are a comma delimited list of all values of certain keys? But, on each iteration of your reducer you overwrite the key with the new value, instead of adding to that keys current value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of `reduce()` is the initial value, so "N/A" will be rendered as long as `spaces` is an array.  Here's what I would do:

```js
const appendData = (initialValue, newValue) => {
  if(!newValue) return initialValue;
  if(!initialValue || initialValue === '') return newValue;
  return `${initialValue}, ${newValue}`;
}

const multiSpaceIdentityInformation = spaces?.reduce(
    (acc, space) => ({
      roomName: appendData(acc.roomName, space.spaceIdentity.roomName),
      roomNumber: appendData(acc.roomNumber, space.spaceIdentity.roomNumber),
      storyName: appendData(acc.storyName, space.buildingStory?.name),
      spaceNumber: appendData(acc.spaceNumber, space.spaceIdentity.number),
      spaceName: appendData(acc.spaceName, space.spaceIdentity.name)
    }),
    {
      roomName: '',
      roomNumber: '',
      storyName: '',
      spaceNumber:'',
      spaceName: ''
    }
  );

Object.keys(multiSpaceIdentityInformation).forEach((key) => {
  if(multiSpaceIdentityInformation[key] === '') 
    multiSpaceIdentityInformation[key] = 'N/A';
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response; I am getting output  like as this `, L1-008-5, L4-002` comma pre appended to the first one as well

Comment: @EnigmaState, Fixed.  You just need to check for the initial value being empty when appending the data.